# How to understand extremal vector?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, quantum-groups

Extremal vectors are defined in Kashiwara's [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077288816). The definition is as follows.

Simple reflections in the Weyl group of $\mathfrak{g}$ acts on the crystal basis of integrable $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$-modules as 
\begin{align}
S_i(b) = 
\begin{cases}
\tilde{f}_i^{\langle h_i, wt(b) \rangle}b, & \langle h_i, wt(b) \rangle \geq 0, \\
\tilde{e}_i^{-\langle h_i, wt(b) \rangle}b, & \langle h_i, wt(b) \rangle \leq 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
An vector $b$ in the crystal basis is called an extremal vector if for any $w \in W$, any $i \in I$, $S_w b$ is killed by $\tilde{e}_i$ or $\tilde{f}_i$. What is the intuition of the definition of extremal vector? Is a highest weight vector an extremal vector? Thank you very much.